# Python-ldap bind

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

Is there a chance to use `ldap.simple_bind_s()` without distinguished name in format `cn=,ou=,dc=,dc=`?

For example I want to use other unique value from LDAP such as `uid`,`gidNumber` or `sAMAccountName`.

This is my `simple_bind_s` call where I don't want to use `cn`. LDAPdb I need to bind to have this awful DN

```
l.simple_bind_s(
    "cn=FirstName LastName,ou=2012,ou=Studenti,ou=People,dc=fri,dc=uniza,dc=sk", passwd
)
```

Any suggestions welcome, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Telling others what you've already tried might help them in answering your question, please update your question with those information.

Answer (score 0):

Per the LDAP RFC, the only option in a simple bind is to specify a DN.
Microsoft Active directory seems to allow to bind with a simple attribute value pair such as mail=john.doe@foo.com, but this will not work with any other LDAP server.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will bind it with DN as I did.